# PDO Code Is not inserting data from Form into MySQL Database

Tags: php, pdo

I have a form, when I submit it to itself, I get no useful errors except:

`PDO::errorInfo(): Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Unable to save record. Please try again.`

I have been banging away at this for hours. I will be fixing the input validation later. For now, I am just trying to get the data into my database, Please advise.

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    // include configuration file
    include 'config/core.php';

    // include database connection
    include 'config/database.php';

    // page header
    $page_title="Create a Record";
    include_once "layout_head.php";

    // if the form was submitted
    if($_POST){

        try{

            echo "<p>Location id is : " . $_POST['location_id']."</p>";
            echo "<p>day is: " . $_POST['day']."</p>";
            echo "<p>Time is " . $_POST['time']."</p>";
            echo "<p>Fee is " . $_POST['fee']."</p>";
            echo "<p>Added is " . $_POST['added']."</p>";
            echo "<p>Game is " . $_POST['game']."</p>";
            echo "<p>Race is " . $_POST['race']."</p>";
            echo "<p>BIH is " . $_POST['bih']."</p>";
            echo "<p>Race is " . $_POST['race']."</p>";
            echo "<p>Handicapped is " . $_POST['handicapped']."</p>";
            echo "<p>Table_size is " . $_POST['table_size']."</p>";
            echo "<p>Tables_used " . $_POST['tables_used']."</p>";
            echo "<p>Cueball size is " . $_POST['cueball']."</p>";
            echo "<p>Equipment is " . $_POST['equipment']."</p>";
            echo "<p>Noise level is " . $_POST['noise']."</p>";
            echo "<p>The space is " . $_POST['space']."</p>";
            echo "<p>Pot is " . $_POST['pots']."</p>";
            echo "<p>Description: " . $_POST['description']."</p>";


            // data validation
            if($_POST['location_id']==0){
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Please select a location.</div>";
            }

            else if($_POST['day']=="empty"){
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Please select a day.</div>";
            }

            else if(empty($_POST['fee'])){ 
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Fee cannot be empty.</div>";
            }

            else if($_POST['added']=="empty"){
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Please select money added.</div>";
            }   

            else if($_POST['game']=="empty"){
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Please select a game.</div>";
            }   

            else if(empty($_POST['race'])){ 
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Race cannot be empty.</div>";
            }

            else if($_POST['handicapped']=="empty"){
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Please select handicapped.</div>";
            }

            else if($_POST['table_size']=="empty"){
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Please select the tables size.</div>";
            }       

            else if(empty($_POST['tables_used'])){ 
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Tables used cannot be empty.</div>";
            }       

            else if($_POST['cueball']=="empty"){
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Please select the cueball size.</div>";
            }       

            else if($_POST['equipment']=="empty"){
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Please rate equipment.</div>";
            }       

            else if($_POST['noise']=="empty"){
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Please rate noise.</div>";
            }               

            else if($_POST['space']=="empty"){
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Please rate space.</div>";
            }       

            else if($_POST['cueball']=="empty"){
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Please select the cueball size.</div>";
            }   

            else if($_POST['pots']=="empty"){
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Please select the pots.</div>";
            }           

            else if(empty($_POST['description'])){ 
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Description cannot be empty.</div>";
            }               
            else{
                // insert query
    /*          $query = "INSERT INTO tournaments SET location_id=:location_id,";
                $query .= "day=:day, time=:time, fee=:fee, added=:added, game=:game, race=:race, ";
                $query .= "bih=:bih, rule=:rule, handicapped=:handicapped, ";
                $query .= "table_size=:table_size, tables_used=:tables_used, cueball=:cueball, ";
                $query .= "equipment=:equipment, noise=:noise, space=:space, pots=:pots, description=:description, created=:created"; */

                $query = "INSERT INTO tournaments (`location_id`, `day`, `time`, `fee`, `added`, `game`, `race`, `bih`, `rule`, `handicapped`,";
                $query .= "`table_size`, `tables_used`, `cueball`, `equipment`, `noise`, `space`, `pots`, `description`, `created`) VALUES ";
                $query .= "(':location_id', ':day', ':time', ':fee', ':added', ':game', ':race', "; 
                $query .= "':bih', ':rule', ':handicapped', ':table_size', ':tables_used', ";
                $query .= "':cueball', ':equipment', ':noise', ':space', ':pots', ':description', ':created')"; 


                // prepare query for execution
                $stmt = $con->prepare($query);

                // bind the parameters
                $stmt->bindParam(':location_id', $_POST['location_id']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':day', $_POST['day']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':time', $_POST['time']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':fee', $_POST['fee']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':added', $_POST['added']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':game', $_POST['game']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':race', $_POST['race']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':bih', $_POST['bih']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':rule', $_POST['rule']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':handicapped', $_POST['handicapped']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':table_size', $_POST['table_size']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':tables_used', $_POST['tables_used']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':cueball', $_POST['cueball']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':equipment', $_POST['equipment']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':noise', $_POST['noise']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':space', $_POST['space']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':pots', $_POST['pots']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':description', $_POST['description']);

                // we need the created variable to know when the record was created
                // also, to comply with strict standards: only variables should be passed by reference
                $created=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $stmt->bindParam(':created', $created);

                // Execute the query
                if($stmt->execute()){
                    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>";
                        echo "Record was saved.";
                    echo "</div>";

                    // empty post array
                    $_POST=array();
                }else{
                    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>";
                        echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
                        print_r($con->errorInfo());
                        echo "Unable to save record. Please try again.";
                    echo "</div>";
                }
            }
        }

        // show error if any
        catch(PDOException $exception){
            die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
        }
    }

    ?>

    <a href='read_tournaments.php' class='btn btn-primary pull-right margin-bottom-1em'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list'></span> Read Records
    </a>

    <!--we have our html form here where user information will be entered-->
    <form action='create_tournament.php' method='post'>
        <table class='table table-bordered table-hover'>
            <tr>
                <td>Location</td>
                <td>
                <?php 
                // read the locations from the database

                // select all categories        
                $query = "SELECT id, name FROM locations ORDER BY name";    

                // prepare query statement and execute
                $stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
                $stmt->execute();

                // put them in a select drop-down
                echo "<select class='form-control' name='location_id'>";
                    echo "<option>Select location...</option>\n";

                    // loop through the locations
                    while ($row_location = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                        extract($row_location);
                        echo "<option value='{$id}'>{$name}</option>\n";
                    }               
                echo "</select>";
                ?>
                </td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td>Day</td>
                <td>
                    <select class='form-control' name="day">
                        <option value="empty">Select Day...</option>
                        <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
                        <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
                        <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
                        <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
                        <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
                        <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
                        <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Time</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='time' class='form-control' required value="<?php echo isset($_POST['time']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['time'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?>" /></td>
            </tr>       
            <tr>
                <td>Fee</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='fee' class='form-control' required value="<?php echo isset($_POST['fee']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['fee'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?>" /></td>
            </tr>       
            <tr>
                <td>Added</td>
                <td>
                <select class='form-control' name="added">
                   <option value="empty">Money Added?</option>
                   <option value="No">No</option>
                   <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                </select> 
                </td>
            </tr>       
            <tr>        

             <tr>
                <td>Game</td> 
                <td>
                    <select class='form-control' name="game">
                       <option value="empty">Select Game...</option>
                       <option value="8-Ball">8-Ball</option>
                       <option value="9-Ball">9-Ball</option>
                       <option value="10-Ball">10-Ball</option>
                       <option value="1-Pocket">1-Pocket</option>
                       <option value="Other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>        
            <tr>
                <td>Side Pots</td> 
                <td>
                    <select class='form-control' name="pots">
                       <option value="empty">Select Pots...</option>                
                       <option value="10 Ball Pot">10 Ball Tickets</option>
                       <option value="Break Pot">Break Pot</option>
                       <option value="No">None</option>
                    </select> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Race</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='race' class='form-control' required value="<?php echo isset($_POST['race']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['race'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ball In Hand</td>
                <td>
                    <select class='form-control' name="bih">
                       <option value="empty">Select Ball In Hand...</option>                
                       <option value="yes">Ball In Hand</option>
                       <option value="no">No Ball In Hand</option>
                    </select> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rule</td>
                <td>
                    <select class='form-control' name="rule">
                       <option value="empty">Select Rule...</option>
                       <option value="Call Pocket">Call Pocket</option>
                       <option value="Any Pocket">Any Pocket</option>   
                       <option value="Call Shot">Call Shot</option>
                    </select>           
                <td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Handicapped?</td>
                <td>
                <select class='form-control' name="handicapped">
                  <option value="empty">Select Handicapped...</option>
                   <option value="No">No</option>
                   <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                </select> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Table Size</td>
                <td>        
                    <select class='form-control' name="table_size">
                       <option value="empty">Select Table Size...</option>              
                       <option value="7 Ft. Bar">7 Ft. Bar</option>
                       <option value="9 Ft. Regulation">9 Ft. Regulation</option>
                    </select>   
                </td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td>Tables Used</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='tables_used' class='form-control' required value="<?php echo isset($_POST['tables_used']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['tables_used'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cueball</td>
                <td>
                    <select class='form-control' name="cueball">
                       <option value="empty">Select Cueball Size...</option>                    
                       <option value="Small Cue Ball">Small Cue Ball</option>
                       <option value="Large Cue Ball">Large Cue Ball</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Equipment</td>
                <td>        
                    <select class='form-control' name="equipment">
                       <option value="empty">Rate Equipment...</option>                 
                       <option value="Excellent">Excellent</option>
                       <option value="Good">Good</option>
                       <option value="Poor">Poor</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Noise</td>
                <td>        
                    <select class='form-control' name="noise">
                       <option value="empty">Rate Noise Level...</option>                   
                       <option value="Quiet">Quiet</option>
                       <option value="Moderate">Moderate</option>
                       <option value="Loud">Loud</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Space</td>
                <td>        
                    <select class='form-control' name="space">
                       <option value="empty">Rate the Space...</option>                 
                       <option value="Excellent">Excellent</option>
                       <option value="Good">Good</option>
                       <option value="Poor">Poor</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>       
            <tr>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td><textarea type='text' name='description' class='form-control' required><?php echo isset($_POST['description']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['description'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type='submit' value='Save' class='btn btn-primary' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript">$('#timepicker1').timepicker();</script> -->
    <?php 
    // page footer
    include_once "layout_foot.php";
    ?>
```

START SQL:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.2.7.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Nov 01, 2015 at 10:00 AM
-- Server version: 5.6.20
-- PHP Version: 5.5.15

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `ptms`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `locations`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `locations` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `yelp` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `youtube` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `locations`
--

INSERT INTO `locations` (`id`, `name`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `phone`, `yelp`, `youtube`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES
(1, 'Spring Valley Inn', '9034 Campo Rd', 'Spring Valley', 'CA', '91977', '(619) 303-7781', 'http://www.yelp.com/biz/spring-valley-inn-cocktail-lounge-spring-valley', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TkOHwpcvzjA', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '2015-10-31 03:48:15'),
(2, 'Five Points Bar', '1881 S Escondido Blvd', 'Escondido', 'CA', '92025', '(760) 740-1139', 'http://www.yelp.com/biz/five-points-bar-escondido-2', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEnd8JIMii4', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '2015-10-31 03:48:15'),
(3, 'The Manhattan', ' 400 Broadway', 'Chula Vista', 'CA', '91910', '(619) 422-6641', 'http://www.yelp.com/biz/manhattan-cocktail-lounge-chula-vista', 'http://localhost/PTMS/create_location.php', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '2015-10-31 03:48:15'),
(7, 'Manny''s Cocktail Lounge', '8729 Broadway', 'La Mesa', 'CA', '91941', '(619) 461-2170', 'http://www.yelp.com/biz/mannys-cocktail-lounge-la-mesa', 'http://localhost/PTMS/create_location.php', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '2015-10-31 03:48:15');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tournaments`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tournaments` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `location_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `day` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `fee` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `added` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `game` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `race` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `rule` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `handicapped` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `table_size` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `tables_used` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `cueball` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `equipment` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `noise` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `space` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `pots` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `locations`
--
ALTER TABLE `locations`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `tournaments`
--
ALTER TABLE `tournaments`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `locations`
--
ALTER TABLE `locations`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tournaments`
--
ALTER TABLE `tournaments`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: I applaud for all the inline syntax...beside that, I think you have syntax error in your mysql insert statement. I think `SET` is for update statement in MYSQL. you should `INSERT INTO {table} (col, col,...) VALUES (val, val,...)`, for accuracy google search..

Comment: As @Andrew stated, INSERT query is not like what you wrote ; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html ; http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: Also, just a side note, this multi `else if` would work but not smartly, what happens if three entries are empty, it will check only one entry every time, instead, remove the `else`, add all error line to a variable, and in the end echo the error variables with all errors in it into the error page

Comment: Alternatively you can check all required fields in one `if` statement, and echo one error something like "all fields marked with an asterisk (\*) are required ", of course you need to put the asterisk character next to each required label in the form

Comment: To what kind of database system is `config/database.php` connecting to?

Comment: I have updated the query variable like Andrew recommended to no avail. Other information stated that I should use back ticks and single quotes  and it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: @VolkerK, I am using 5.6.20 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: Same problems. Thanks for all of you providing the validation advice, I am going to have to google around on that, I am sure there is a plethora of information on that topic. I am fairly new and have some reading to do...   I have updated the code above to show the edits. Still getting same exact error as stated in my question summary.

Comment: I have added a SQL dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing error information from the connection object, but not looking at error information from the statement object. You might want to look at the [manual entry for PDO::errorInfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php).
You also catch PDOException, but we can't see any code where those exceptions are enabled, see the [manual entry for PDO::setAttribute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) in case you're not aware that you need to enable these.

There also appears to be a column in your statement called `bih`, but this column is nowhere in the table configuration you've pasted.

Comment: Thank you @Thorbear. Your advice lead me to change from print_r($con->errorInfo()); to print_r($stmt->errorInfo()); and gave me the same BIH error. I was, in fact, missing that column in the database. I learned something from you about difference in error reporting (connection vs. sql execution). Everything working now that I added BIH (Ball in hand). Pool player terminology.